# How can get data between two dates?

Tags: php

1. Suppose i have a set of strings formatted in a way:

270|in-profit.biz|test|3|2012-10-27 00:00:00||just for test

```
379|yourhourly.com|Yourhourly.com|3|2015-03-11 00:00:00||101% After
1 Hour<br>   How do i get value like as:

$value1 = 270

$value2 = in-profit.biz

$value3 = test

$value4 = 3
```

of each line

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for that

```
$string = "270|in-profit.biz|test|3|2012-10-27 00:00:00||just for test";
preg_match_all('/(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|/i', $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$value1  = $matches[1][0];
$value2 = $matches[2][0];
$value3 = $matches[3][0];
$value4 = $matches[4][0];


echo $value1;
echo $value2;
echo $value3;
echo $value4;
```

Output:

```
270
in-profit.biz
test
3
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/MZ68rY)

---

Alternatively you can use [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/explode)

```
$string = "270|in-profit.biz|test|3|2012-10-27 00:00:00||just for test";

$matches = explode('|', $string );

$value1  = $matches[0];
$value2 = $matches[1];
$value3 = $matches[2];
$value4 = $matches[3];


echo $value1;
echo $value2;
echo $value3;
echo $value4;
```

Output:

```
270
in-profit.biz
test
3
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/wcwR1j)

Comment: Please don't suggest `split()` to OP! It's deprecated. I think `preg_split()` would be better here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string like

```
$str = 'aaa|bbb|ccc|ddd|eeeee|fffffff'
```

or any set of values separated by `|`, you can split it using `split()` like such

```
$results = split('\|', $str);
```

This will give you an array of strings that you will be able to work with

```
$results[0] = 'aaa'
$results[1] = 'bbb'
...
$results[5] = 'fffffff'
```

Comment: You need to escape the `|`